# Rails callback does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, callback

I have a callback in my model:

```
before_validation :downcase_title, :populate_empty_fields

private

def downcase_title
  title
end

def populate_empty_fields
  title2 = title.split(',').first if !title2
end
```

but they do not work. well, data updated if I log out value from console (puts ...), but after model saved I see that no changes applied.

For example for first method, I see that it works if I write it like

```
def downcase_title
  title.downcase
end
```

What is wrong with these methods?

Comment: What is behavior you’re trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change attributes, you should add `self` before the attribute:

```
def downcase_title
  self.title = title.downcase
end

def populate_empty_fields
  self.title2 = title.split(',').first if !title2
end
```